# Query to list employees who have more than 30 days leave from the from date and to date of the leave

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table

```
emp_leave 
emp_id
leave_from
leave_to
```

Can any one help me to write a query to select the `emp_id` whose total leave days are more than 30.

The question may be very basic but to my level.

Comment: Please be more specific about your question.

Comment: select empi_id from  emp_leave where leave_to-leave_from>30

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT emp_id, sum(Noofdays) as days from(
SELECT emp_id, DATEDIFF(day, leave_from, leave_to) AS Noofdays  from emp_leave) A group by  emp_id having sum(Noofdays)>30

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

SELECT emp_id,DATEDIFF(`leave_to`, `leave_from`) AS days FROM emp_leave GROUP BY emp_id HAVING days > 30;